# WSO2 user synchronisation

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am reviewing WSO2 Identity Server as a self registration component. I have installed and set it up as per the documentation. However we are using Omada as a role manager and I need to synchronise the new users with the Omada user store. I have not been able to find how to go about this. A general method description to get me going would help a lot.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of Omada user store. But you should be able to add that as a secondary user store to the WSO2 IS

Comment: Thank you Thusitha. Omada uses a sql database so I am trying to set this up as a secondary user store using JDBCUserStoreManager in the WSO2 configuration. I am not sure however what to set in the Driver Name field ? Are there any examples for this ? Thaks again

Comment: @Brian What the SQL database your using? Then We might be able to help.